# sess_create(); not working in Codeigniter 3.0 after sess_destroy();

Tags: codeigniter, session

Is it possible to keep flash data after session destroy in codeigniter.i saw several answers on stackoverflow but none of them works.

Below is my logout method.

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->session->sess_create(); 
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have been logged out   successfully.');
    redirect('welcome');        
}
```

Getting error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::sess_create()

I m using codeigniter 3.0.

Comment: Intialise session `$this->load->driver('session');`

Comment: Is sess_create() a valid method? Never seen it. Just searched the driver, and doesn't find it.

Comment: sess_create is not a valid method in CI 3.0

Answer (score 4):

Do nothing just `remove or comment` the bottom line and try:-

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();

// $this->session->sess_create();
```

Also set in `config.php` file

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

and read [this link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/700)

Comment: sess_destroy works but what about flash message after destroying session

Comment: Not available in Codeignitor 3.0

Comment: As an added note if you need to use `$this->session->sess_create();` you can use `$this->session->__construct();`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `cookie` instead of a session

```
$this->load->helper('cookie'); // Call the helper
$this->input->cookie('logoutstatus', TRUE); //set the cookie
```

In the page where you want to display the message, check for that cookie

`$this->load->helper('cookie');` // Call the helper again in that view page

```
$checkStatus = get_cookie('logoutstatus');
if($checkStatus){ //if its available
//display thge message and then delete the cookie
delete_cookie("logoutstatus");
}
```

**NOTE:** It would be a lot better if you just include the `cookie` helper in your `autoload.php` configuration.